# Linq query - reading nested XML to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to parse nested XML file

The structure is (simplified) following:

```
<CARS_LIST_OUTPUT>
  <RESPONSE>
    <DATETIME>2014-09-03T12:12:55Z</DATETIME>
    <CARS_LIST>
      <CAR>
         <CID>12123</CID>
         <PARTS_LIST>
            <PART>
              <ID>QWEDS23</ID>
            </PART>
            <PART>
              <ID>QWEDS26</ID>
            </PART>
         </PARTS_LIST>
      </CAR>
      <CAR>
         <CID>44123</CID>
         <PARTS_LIST>
            <PART>
              <ID>QWED101</ID>
            </PART>
            <PART>
              <ID>QAADS23</ID>
            </PART>
         </PARTS_LIST>
      </CAR>
     </CARS_LIST>
   </RESPONSE>
 <CAR_LIST_OUTPUT>
```

I need to make a dictionary of all parts ID and their corresponding car id (CID), i.e.

QWEDS23, 12123
QWEDS26, 12123
QWED101, 44123
QAADS23, 44123

So far I got to this point:

```
        var nodes = 
            from c in carDirectory.Descendants("CAR")
            select new 
        {
            parts = c.Descendants("PART")
                .Select(part => new {
                        ID = part.Element("ID").Value,
                        c.Element("CID").Value
                        }).ToDictionary(r => r.ID)
        };
```

But this results in a list of dictionaries. Is it possible to achieve what I need? If yes, how can I improve my solution? Thank you for ideas!

Comment: Off-topic, but wouldn't it be more... "logical" to have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, the `string` being your IDs (`12123`) and the `List<string>` being all corresponding parts (`QWEDS23` and `QWEDS26`)?

Comment: Actually this is specifically required to have a dictionary <string, string>

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. Yet I'd have a talk with the "requirer" about that :p

Comment: @Kilazur, the goal is to simplify process of finding a car ID knowing part ID. Therefore it is best to have a dictionary where the key is value that is being searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
carDirectory.Descendants("CAR")
       .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("ID")
           .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
               (string) e,
               (string) x.Element("CID"))))
       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but is there a way to account for situation, when there is a duplicate in a string which is used as a key?

Comment: you mean duplicate part ids?

Comment: you can fix it using groupby, add this after SelectMany: `.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);`